# How can I build a DLL using the OpenSSL FIPS static library on Windows?

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, linker, openssl, fips

I asked this on the openssl-users mailing list with no replies, so I thought I'd try here.

I am trying to build a Windows DLL that includes the static OpenSSL FIPS libraries. I built the FIPS libraries using `perl Configure fips --with-fipslibdir=... -no-shared` and then `nmake -f ms\nt.mak`. I'm using openssl-fips-2.0.5, openssl-1.0.1j, and MS Visual Studio 2010.

Now I'm trying to link the resulting libraries into my DLL. I've followed the instructions in the [OpenSSL FIPS 2.0 User's Guide](http://openssl.org/docs/fips/UserGuide-2.0.pdf), setting a bunch of environment variables (FIPS_LINK, FIPS_CC, FIPS_CC_ARGS, etc.) and then called `fipslink.pl`. But I'm getting a "First stage Link failure".

It reports "Integrity check OK" and then compiles fips_premain.c, but when linking the DLL I get a bunch of "locally defined symbol _time64 imported" warnings (as well as strncmp, _errno, abort, fprintf, and others), and then some unresolved external symbols including:

__imp_strncpy
__imp_qsort
__imp_wcsstr
__imp_vsnwprintf

All of the errors come from libeayfips32.lib, libeaycompat32.lib, and ssleay32.lib.

I've played around with adding and removing things like `/NODEFAULTLIB:msvcrt` and `/NODEFAULTLIB:libcmtd`, and building with `/MT` or `/MD` or neither, but I keep getting linker errors each time. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

open file `ms\nt.mak` then modify line #28  by adding  `msvcrt.lib msvcrtd.lib` at the end , to be like:

```
EX_LIBS=ws2_32.lib gdi32.lib advapi32.lib crypt32.lib user32.lib msvcrt.lib msvcrtd.lib
```

then run : `nmake -f ms\nt.mak` from visual studio command prompt.I hope that no linker messages will appear.

Also try to build the DLL by `nmake -f ms\ntdll.mak`

Comment: This made no difference. I can build a DLL successfully and have been doing so for years but I want a static library.

Answer (score 2):

I speculate that the "-no-shared" switch to the Configure script statically links the C standard library.  You'd get your static OpenSSL FIPS library, but it would include implementations of printf and friends, as you actually experience.

Comment: Perhaps this is true but it doesn't help me. I *can* build a shared version (i.e. DLLs) but I want to build a static library.